# How to make a WCF service return a NON-generic FaultException with additional Data

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, fault

We've got a couple hundred WCF services that call stored procedures via ADO.NET. We'd like the client to handle server exceptions a little more intelligently. I have working code using the generic FaultException with a custom fault type, but I thought as long as I'm here, I'd like to try throwing the non-generic FaultException, and put all the extra information in its Data collection.

But I can't make that work. The FaultException is created as I desire on the server, and I throw it, but somebody's catching it and throwing a new FaultException with the standard Data values: "MethodName", parameters, "AsyncActionDescription". So I'm either doing it wrong, or you can't do that.

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on this. Everything is about using generic FaultException<T>. For that reason alone, I think I'll just stick with the generic, especially since I've got it working already. And because STRONGLY TYPED which somebody will no doubt rightly remind me.

I'm just curious about what's going on here.

Comment: Why do you think (or seem to think based on your third paragraph) that `FaultException<T>` is not strongly typed?

Comment: @Tim You read me backwards. I think of FaultException<T> as *more* "strongly typed" than a run-of-the-mill non-generic FaultException with some arbitrary entries added to its Data member. I said I *should* use FaultException<T> *because* "strongly typed". Not to mention, I've already got it working.

Comment: Ooops....sorry.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No prob! Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here, by not finding the answer, is that WCF strongly enforces separation of concerns regarding the service faults. Fundamental question is "How does the client know what to do?" From client stand point, its either S_OK or !S_OK to paraphrase HRESULT from COM.

The idea behind not providing specific fault to the client is in fact that client knows much less then a service about the problem. On top of that, client is even less inclined to understand how to **compensate** for service failure. Exceptions are sometimes very technology specific and this would introduce form of coupling between the client and the service.

You can use [Fault Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx) that communicate something to the client. `FaultException<T>` can help convert specific exceptions to Faults.

I would recommend you read a [WCF bible book from Juval](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043D2DUK). Chapter 6 is full of good information around Faults.

And there is IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults service behavior. Good for debugging but don't use it in production.

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults = true)]
class MyService : IMyContract
{...}
```